# How to enable activity for all system languages

Tags: android, string, android-activity, localization, translation

I'm modding an app. The app has a feature that shows contact information of a caller on a smart band. The problem is that it only shows when the phone is setup in English. As soon as the language is changed that feature disappears. I made sure the strings in the language I want are correct and include the text for that feature. Can anyone suggest what files or strings I should be looking into?

Comment: Activities aren't enabled on a language by language basis.  They either exist or they don't.

Comment: There's some code that's hiding that feature when the language isn't English. Find that.

Comment: Thank you, TheWanderer where should I look for it? is it likely to be in the default strings?

Comment: @DanielLeal it is hard to tell without more informations or at least code where you think issue is happening. I don't know how did you set layout so one of the possibilities that, the word is there but it is not visible because it can not fit (if it is for example longer than English word), this is just a guess.

Comment: I figured it out, if the system language wasn't english or chinese there was a code that disabled that layout. I had to change it to gedDefault() and it resolved. Kind regards